# SQL datetime compare

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I want to get some values from my table an there are some conditions about its datetime columns.

I want to get all hotel values of a stated city from my table, which is named "LocalHotels". Also I should declare two `DateTime`values. First value should be less than or equal to hotel's value in *"start"* column, which is `datetime` data type. Second value should be greater than or equal to hotel's value in *"deadline"* column, which is `datetime` data type, either.

All `datetime` values in these two columns are inserted in German `CultureInfo` format.

When I stated query below, there are no problems;

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM LocalHotels WHERE city='LONDON' AND start <='5.12.2015 00:00:00' AND deadline >='8.12.2015 00:00:00' ORDER BY city";
```

However when I changed day value of `DateTime` values from one digit to two digits, as I stated in below;

```
string query "SELECT * FROM LocalHotels WHERE city='LONDON' AND start <='15.12.2015 00:00:00' AND deadline >='18.12.2015 00:00:00' ORDER BY city"
```

I got an SQLException which indicates;

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Is it mysql or sql server? Maybe your database manager thinks your `15` and `18` are months, not days? Have you tried with a value less or equal `12`?

Comment: it is sql server. I tried month values, which are less than 12, and result did not change.

Comment: When writing out dates in strings to compare against, use the universal format YYYYMMDD always - no problem.

Comment: With date literals I prefer the ODBC formats: Date would be `{d'2015-12-05'}`, Time is `{t'23:30:00'}` and DateTime is `{ts'2015-12-05 23:30:00'}`. These formats don't need any (implicit) conversion.

Comment: @Shnugo - unfortunately `YYYY-MM-DD` doesn't work in all locales, for example, french ([reference](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries))

Comment: @Bridge, that's why there is the `{d''}` around :-) All suggested formats (also yours) will need some kind of conversion...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Even though in Europe and everywhere in the world it makes perfect sense to use the month as the second of three items in the date. In the US and in this case, apparently, SQL's date time is MM.DD.YYYY, so you're going for the 15th month and 18th month

Therefore you should use

```
string query "SELECT * FROM LocalHotels WHERE city='LONDON' AND start <='12.15.2015 00:00:00' AND deadline >='12.18.2015 00:00:00' ORDER BY city"
```

or

```
string query "SELECT * FROM LocalHotels WHERE city='LONDON' AND start <='2015-12-15' AND deadline >='2015-12-18' ORDER BY city"
```

Answer (score 11):

Try changing

```
15.12.2015 00:00:00
```

to

```
2015-12-15 00:00:00
```

and same format for the other date also.

Answer (score 8):

You can view SQL Server's date and time format for yourself by running this query:

```
SELECT
    GETDATE()
```

As you can see the format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MMM.  Stick to this and you won't run into any unexpected conversion errors.

**EDIT**

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is a standard date format.  From [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-string-literal-formats-for-datetime):

> The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an international standard with unambiguous specification. Also, this format isn't affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE setting.

For this reason I would recommend it above all other formats.  Examples:

`2020-02-25`
`20200225`
`2020-02-25T18:37:00`

Comment: This works for `SQL Server (starting with 2008)`, `Azure SQL Database`, `Azure SQL Data Warehouse`, `Parallel Data Warehouse`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
```

or

```
select convert(varchar,getDate(),112)
```

or

```
select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 111), '/','-')
```

Test out the queries above to get the date in the desired format (replace `GetDate()` with your date, or dateColumn). 
As others pointed out you need the format YYYY-MM-DD.